# How to add external library in a glue job using python shell

Tags: aws-glue

I tried to run a Glue job in python-shell by adding external dependencies (like pyathena, pytest,etc ..) as python egg file/ whl file in the job configurations as mentioned in the AWS documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html.

The Glue job is configured under VPC having no internet and its execution resulted in the below error.

> WARNING: The directory '/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not
> owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been
> disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If
> executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None,
> redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
> object at 0x7fd05d6a4f28>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect
> timeout=15)')'

I even tried modifying my python script with the below code

```
import os
import site
import importlib
from setuptools.command import easy_install
install_path = os.environ['GLUE_INSTALLATION']

libraries = ["pyathena"]

for lib in libraries:
    easy_install.main( ["--install-dir", install_path , lib] )

importlib.reload(site)
```

On executing the above code i faced below error

> Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/pyathena/: [Errno 99] Cannot
> assign requested address -- Some packages may not be found! Couldn't
> find index page for 'pyathena' (maybe misspelled?)

Can i have sample code snippet to generate an egg/whl file for external python packages and to add those part of Glue python-shell job

Comment: Can you try this steps https://helicaltech.com/external-python-libraries-aws-glue-job/ and also make sure that vpc you are using has a S3 endpoint

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy -  thankyou, steps mentioned in the above link helped to resolve the issues

Comment: I have added answer. Please mark it as answered if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this [doc](https://helicaltech.com/external-python-libraries-aws-glue-job/) which has steps in detail for packaging a python library. Also make sure that your VPC has s3 endpoint [enter link description here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/vpc-endpoints-s3.html) as traffic will not leave AWS network when you run a Glue job inside VPC.